# Is the $||u||L_{(U)}^p$ greater than the average of u over U?

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality

Is it true that for any function u, the Lp-norm, $||u||L_{(U)}^p$ is always greater than or equal to the average value of u over U for all p?

Comment: Your question is not clear. What is $u$ and $L_p$ ?

Comment: @Youem. That Is the Lp norm of the function u. U is the set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $u= 1$, $p<∞$,  and $U=[-1/10,1/10]$ then the average value is $1$,with
$$‖u‖_{L^p(U)} = (1/5)^{1/p}  < 1 $$

For $p=∞$, $\frac{1}{|U|}\left|\int_U u\right| ≤ ‖u‖_{L^∞}$ just by Holder's inequality. (In fact Holder lets you get more counterexamples for the $p<∞$ case.)